# Drupal 8: Link content type with another content type

Tags: drupal, module, relationship, content-type, drupal-8

Anyone know how to link a content type with another content type? I mean "B" content type have a select field that can link to "A" content type. Not parent or child differentiate, but both "A" content type and "B" content type have relationship. Drupal 8, not 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) is your answer.

It comes with **Drupal** core

Comment: While the information at the link may answer the question, the content explaining how to accomplish what's being asked should still be in the answer itself (cited and quoted).

Comment: it did link to content type, but it cannot link contents inside the content type. Like "ABC" post in content type "B" link with "XYZ" post in content type "A".